# Is there a name for a data table composed of a list of map objects?

Tags: dynamic, groovy, nomenclature

In dynamic languages, a map is often interchangeable with an object so a list of map objects is extremely common--it seems to be the default way to store a table. For instance, in Groovy querying a database table without a predefined mapping returns a list of maps matching the database.

At this point I've built tools to display these as formatted text, use them as backing for GUI table views, read from the DB and read from an excel spreadsheet, but I still don't know what to call them.

Is there a common name for this structure combination?  RowMap?  ListMap?  ListMapTable?  Since I typically use Java it's not something that has come up before but describing these groovy objects as a "List of similar maps" is getting old.

Comment: in jdbc it's a ResultSet )

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't make a very good generalized term--like if in groovy I asked for (def resultSet) as a parameter used to initialize a grid display I'm pretty sure nobody would know what to pass.  MapList maybe?  Suppose I released a library of functions that worked on this object structure--would calling it a MapList Table library make sense to anyone?